# CKE edtior, AngularJS, codesnippets

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compilation, ckeditor, ng-bind-html

The best thing is start from the begining.. so :
At project im working on (AngularJS) I'm using CKEditor as wysiwyg editor. Everything was working very good till I wanted to add codesnippet functionallity.

CKE produces pure html code, which I can bind to a model to see in real time what's happening. On my side I've been using ng-bind-html to see the results and it worked well. Every basic-html code was working, bold, italic, headings.. fonts, size etc.

When CodeSnippet plugin (http://ckeditor.com/addon/codesnippet) went in...
It stopped working (I mean the codesnippet part).
Example of not-working HTML(btw CKE produces code with ‚&lt and &gt instead of normal tags < and >.. so I have to replace them… but nevermind its not an issue :) ).
Example of snippet (which doesnt work on ng-bind side):

```
<code class="language-      html">&lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;Test&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</code>
```

The problem is that inside editor everything works good,  but outside (when binded to ng-bind-html directive), its not.

What Ive tried so far:
- I included CSS files which CKE editor uses inside.. worthless.
- code snippet plugin uses highlight.js so I tried to transform CKE html code into highlight.js one.. and it worked!
example:

```
<div compile="true" hljs language="css”>whatever</div>
```

But the problem is CKE editor produces complex text (including code snippets, other stuff, quotes etc..). So If i put all of this into HLJS directive.. it highlights everything. Its not what I wanted to achieve.

My solution to this problem was adding dynamically directives with HLJS + normal html code. Result example:
(hljs directive its angular directive for hightlight.js) :

```
<div id="hl" compile="true" hljs language="css">example</div>
<p><strong>Damn</strong></p>
<div id="hl" compile="true" hljs language="cpp">Other snippet</div>
```

To make it work I had to recompile whole code I’ve added.. So I’ve put it into directive which has watch and recompiles code once its updated.

And.. It worked!! but… and here comes the real problem:

*it only works for HTML-valid code snippets because $compile somehow validates all this stuff inside… whats happening? '<' tag is transformed into '& lt;' … If I open some HTML tag.. its immediatly closes it.. (if I 'forgot' about it) and many other weird and unacceptable stuff.

Do you have any idea? 
I've tried to explain the issue as clear as possible but if you have any further questions..

Comment: No ideas at all? ...

Comment: That's why I hate angularJS. You have to add a separate angular file for each element like, ngTagInputs, checklist-mode, chosen etc..